# Trouble dismissing popover when deep inside nested tableview

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad program that has the following structure:

Viewcontroller VC1
    VC 1 declares UIPopover controller
       inside Popover controller I call a Nav controller which calls a TableView Controller TC1

TC1 pushes to a second Tableviewer Controller TC2

When the user selects a row in the table I want to dismiss the Popup.

Here is the code inside TC2:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

I'm getting an error `popOverController not declared`

So I figure that since I'm inside the `Tableviewcontroller` object it doesn't know about the `popOverController`.

What I don't have the first clue about is how to get a message back to the `popOverController` delegate (if that's even right) to send the dismiss command.

This appears to be a well versed question on the internet, but no one seems to be doing drill down tableviews inside a popup so I can't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

set TC2 delegate as TC1 and TC1 delegate as VC1. inside didselectrow function in TC2, call delegate function in TC1 which inturn calls function in VC1. there in VC1 you can easily dismiss the popover. The same problem i have faced and solved it in this fashion.

Thanks for your navcontrol suggestion to push viewcontroller onto popover. It helped me to show drill down tableviews inside popover.